# Parsing a string and finding specific text in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a string which contains, lets say word "key" 5 times. Each time I see the word "key" in that string I want to print some text. How can I parse that string, find all "key" words and print the texts accordingly? 5 words "key" - 5 printed texts. This needs to be done in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [**`Regex.Matches`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx):

```
string input = ...
string toPrint = ...

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, "key"))
    Console.WriteLine(toPrint);
```

**EDIT**: If by "word", you mean 'whole words', you need a different regex, such as:

```
@"\bkey\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a loop, you can use the substring() method which offers the starting position parameter, and with each iteration you would advance the starting position; loop exits when you reach the string-not-found condition.  EDIT: as for printing the text, that would depend on where you want to print it.  EDIT2: You also need to consider whether the target string can appear in a manner you would  not consider a true "hit":

```
          The key to success, the master key, is getting off your keyster...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an extension method I use for strings to get Indexes of a substring since .Net only provides IndexOf (single result for first substring match).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int[] IndexesOf(this string str, string sub)
    {
        int[] result = new int[0];

        for(int i=0; i < str.Length; ++i)
        {
            if(i + sub.Length > str.Length)
                break;
            if(str.Substring(i,sub.Length).Equals(sub))
            {
                Array.Resize(ref result, result.Length + 1);
                result[result.Length - 1] = i;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You could use the extension method for all instances of key to print something

```
int[] indexes = stringWithKeys.IndexesOf("key");

foreach(int index in indexes)
{
    // print something
}
```

I know my code example may be longest but the extension method is reusable and you could place it in a "utility" type library for later use.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a multiple word string, you could use LINQ.

```
string texttosearch;
string texttofind;

string[] source = texttosearch.Split(new char[] { '.', '?', '!', ' ', ';', ':', ',' },    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 var matchQuery = from word in source
                     where word.ToLowerInvariant() == texttofind.ToLowerInvariant()
                     select word;

    foreach (string s in matchquery)
       console.writeline(whatever you want to print);
```